# File Upload using ajax and jquery in spring

Tags: java, jquery

```
var urlUpload = "${root}manager/uploadFile.html";
var params = $('#topicForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlUpload,
        data: params,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });

@RequestMapping(value="/manager/uploadFile.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(@ModelAttribute("topicForm") TopicForm topicForm,        
@RequestParam("topicDoc") MultipartFile multipartFile ModelMap model) { ... }
```

I am getting the below exception

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was
>   rejected because no multipart boundary was found.

The plugin is working fine thank you.

```
var urlUpload = "${root}manager/uploadFile.html?categoryId="+$("#category").val()+"&topicName="+$("#topicName").val();
 $.ajaxFileUpload({
 url:urlUpload, 
 secureuri:false,
 fileElementId:'fileupload',
 dataType: 'html',
 success: function (data, status) {
   alert("success");
 }
});
```

The plugin is working fine, now i need to send few form fields to the controller along with the input file. in the above ajax call i appended the values to url. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Just send the ajax query with url being your site + whatever is in the `RequestMapping` value and make it a POST.

Comment: Your question is unclear: are you looking for a file upload plugin, do you not know how to use the plugin that you've got, or do you not know how to process the file in your controller? There are existing answers on SO for all three of these cases.

Comment: Please reply to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're attempting to upload a URL-encoded serialization of the form, while claiming that it's multipart (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) of JQuery's `serialize()` function).

You need to use a plugin that will create the proper request. [Here's](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) one that I've used.

Alternatively, you can use [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) to upload files. I haven't done this.

Comment: Can we send additional data to the controller including the input file (fileElementId:'fileToUpload') using this plugin